# sql - inner join performing cross join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have the following table structure.

```
create table t1 (
  id int,
  tno int
  );

  create table t2 (
  id int,
  detailno int
  );

  insert into t1 values (101,1);
  insert into t1 values (101,2);

  insert into t2 values (101,7);
  insert into t2 values (101,8);
```

When I perform the following query:

```
select * from t1
inner join t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.detailno = 8;
```

It performs a `cross join` and returns

```
id | tno | id | detailno
101 | 1  | 101 |    8
101 | 2  | 101 |    8
```

It is basically performing a **`Cross join` instead of an `inner join`**. Could you please help me return only a single result instead - since `detail id = 8` is in the `where` clause ? I have shortened the table structure and the query for easier understanding. Here is the sql fiddle for the above code. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92c98/1

Comment: It's not performing a cross join.  Since you have 2 records in t1 101, both 101.1 and 101.2 and two records in t2 both 101.7 and 101.8.  The 2 101.1 in t1 both tie to both records in t2.  so both 101.1 and 101.2 get a 101.8 and a 101.7 but the 7 is excluded due to you where clause.  The cross join you perceive is because the join criteria joins to two records.  Put another way.... What would you expect the system to do when both tables each contain 101 which one should each join to from t1 to t2? 1*2 = 2 rows...  which tno do you expect in the results.. and why?

Comment: If you reverse the query, it becomes clearer: First, you select the one row from `t2` with `t2.detailno = 8` and then you join this row using `id` with `t1` and you get two rows, because `id` 101 is present two times in `t1`.

Comment: @Smutje; @xQbert: Okay, i get it now. Could you suggest a way to resolve it? I wish my return answer to be [`code`] 101 | 8 [`code`]

Comment: if tno from table t1 is not important than you can use Distinct to get result you want... Take a look [here!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7c1f/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is doing exactly as you've asked it to do.

What is the one result you're expecting?
If you only want one line then maybe you're better off making the query more specific by adding a condition such as

```
WHERE t2.detailno = 8
AND t1.tno = 1
```

which will whittle down the results more.

#### Edit

If you're unsure what the value of `t1.tno` is going to be then could you not pass that in as a parameter? It might be more clear if you can explain why you're expecting `t1.tno = 2`.

You'd then potentially end up with something like this if you pass it in as a parameter.

```
WHERE t2.detailno = 8
AND t1.tno = @tno
```

Comment: i want the result to be 101 | 2 | 8. If i write the query the way you suggested it works definitely but it would be a overhead since I do not know what the value of t1.tno is going to be

Comment: i got it now. I will have to add one more condition to get it working. It wont work otherwise. I got stunned by the original enormous query. Now i realize my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Join is working as expected.

Execute this to check:

```
select * from t1
inner join t2
on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Every id is making join with another table's id and which is correct for join.

So if you want result as your expectation you need to pass t1.tno and add into where condition as there are multiple record in another table for same id (t1.id).